# Ember.js jsBin template/skeleton with the latest Ember.js code

Tags: ember.js, jsbin

Whatever Ember.js links I was including on jsbin is no longer working. So I would like this thread to have the latest working template/skeleton of Ember.js for jsBin.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a link to jsbin with the latest Ember.js code: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/239/edit

In future you can find updated links here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the Ember.js custom JS Bin at http://emberjs.jsbin.com.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JSBin with the latest EmberJS: http://jsbin.com/neham/1/edit

**Where can I get the links for the latest release of Ember.js?**

> You can find the latest release under the 'Builds' tab in the official Ember.js website. That would be [here](http://emberjs.com/builds/#/release).

**Where can I get the links to the latest builds of Ember.js?**

> You can also find the latest beta builds under the 'Builds' tab in the official Ember.js website. That would be [here](http://emberjs.com/builds/#/beta).

**What is the compatible version of Handlebars.js?**

> Ember is very specific about what version of Handlebars it requires. For this, I usually check the ember-source.gemspec file in [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js). 
>   Before you check the .gemspec file, ensure that you switch to the right version of the emberjs build that you are using.

[image]